# How do I redirect my edge flow here?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to redirect the edge flow here as shown with blue line without breaking the quad based geometry?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a problem if it adds 2 vertices on your outer edge loop? Because you could simply do that:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem (I think) as I have a shrinkwrap modifier supporting the mesh. Let me try. Thanks for your reply dude! I feel so stupid to not think flexibly. Also let me thank you for being so prompt on this website and helping me a couple of times!

Comment: you're welcome  ;)

Comment: Well it works! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just another option in case the outer edge loop would matter, you could do something like this (but I personally think @moonboots answer results in a better mesh):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I feel your's is also very tight. I don't see much of a difference between your's and @moonboots.